# Incorporating both Contacts and ContactsContract into an Android application

Tags: android, contacts

Greetings all,

I realize this issue has been posed before in other forms, and believe me, I have been searching the net for days trying to find the answer.  However, I'm fairly new to Android and Java, and I need a little guidance please.

I presently have two version of my app, one for Android 1.5 and 1.6, and another for 2.0 and beyond.  As you probably guessed, it's because the Contacts API is different.

I recently became aware that it was possible to combine both methods into a single app, by using dynamically loadable classes.  Very cool!  After days of attempts, I still haven't been able to do it successfully...  or at least, it won't run.

I have come across 3 examples of how to do this - one by Google, called "Business Card", another that had something to do with Spinners, and a 3rd was something someone here created.  My problem is that each one seems to me to have a showstopper.

I'm using Eclipse on Windows 7.  My app was first created for A1.5, so that's the one I'm upgrading.  What's happening is that my ContactsAccessorNewApi class needs to import the ContactContracts, and according to Eclipse, that won't work because my project was originally built without support for it.  Hence, it won't run.  I've tried adding the android.jar for SDK level 5 into the project, but that creates a whole mess of other problems.

My code for this pat of my app is exactly like the Google example "Business Card" - so if someone could help me cross this hurdle, I'd be very grateful.  I'll be happy to post any code that you need to answer my question.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> another that had something to do with Spinners

If you mean [this sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/Contacts/Spinners/), that's mine.

> I'm using Eclipse on Windows 7. My app was first created for A1.5, so that's the one I'm upgrading. What's happening is that my ContactsAccessorNewApi class needs to import the ContactContracts, and according to Eclipse, that won't work because my project was originally built without support for it.

You need to set your build target (Project Properties > Android) to be high enough that `ContactsContract` exists (`android-5` or higher).

So long as your `android:minSdkVersion` in your manifest is set to support earlier versions of Android (e.g., 3 for Android 1.5), your app will still install on older emulator AVDs and devices.

> I've tried adding the android.jar for SDK level 5 into the project, but that creates a whole mess of other problems.

Yeah, don't do that.

Comment: Yep, that's the sample code I was thinking of.  :)  Sorry I couldn't remember it at the time.  I did exactly what you said, and everything looks ok, except I'm getting "Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1" - Do you know off the top of your head how to solve that one?

Comment: @Joel: I haven't seen that with Eclipse, but, then again, I don't use Eclipse much. Try Project > Clean and see if that helps any.

Comment: I actually solved it by creating a new project, and importing my source code back into it.  It apparently was just grouchy because I created the project with Android 1.5 as the target build.  Thanks for your assistance!!